# How to display a loaded image on a pygame.Overlay()

Tags: python, image, pygame

I am trying to use overlays in pygame to display video. The trouble is that my frames are loaded as RGB Surface()s while Overlay().display() requires YUV format.

I saw that pygame.camera module contains a colorspace() function that should be able to convert RGB Surface() to YUV one. Does anyone know how to do the trick? The conversion and the displaying?

pygame.camera.colorspace() is not very well documented.

If this doesn't work, does anyone know how to do this by using PIL to convert to YUV?

Comment: I don't have my linux box with me right now but from the documentation is it not `yuv_surface = pygame.camera.colorspace(rgb_surface,"YUV")`? I'll have a look when I get the chance.

Comment: Yes, but how to get YUV data from it to display it on Overlay()?

Comment: How are you loading frames? Most tutorials I see for overlay handle this by loading in frames with the required format

Comment: At the moment I have them saved as JPEG images. So I get them as RGB Surface() by pygame.image.load(). Keeping them in memory as Surfaces can rais out of memory error, and blitting them to screen doesn't produce smooth video as I hoped. Even at only 24 FPS sometimes it stutters.

Comment: Regardless of how you display them, loading in JPEG's will be slow in python. I don't think an overlay will solve this.

Comment: Nope, IO is not a problem as they are preloaded and converted. What is best the blitting operation is unmeasurably short. I.e. time() difference is 0.0. But graphics still have trouble. Also, scaling any image manualy to fit the screen is catastrophically slow. Overlay does the scaling automatically regardless the resolution of an image and it is fast and anti-aliassed. Well, it is made to show video. Surface() is not.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't had much time to play with .Overlay()

but the colorspace function seems to go as follows:

```
yuv_surface = pygame.camera.colorspace(rgb_surface,"YUV")
```

This example runs without error:

```
import pygame
import pygame.camera

pygame.init()
pygame.camera.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((400,400))
rgb_surface = pygame.Surface((400,400))

yuv_surface = pygame.camera.colorspace(rgb_surface,"YUV")

screen.blit(yuv_surface,(0,0))

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

while True:
    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(30)
```